# How to understand the quotation about the member functions with ref-qualifiers?

Tags: c++, c++11

As per the [document](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/language/member_functions.html#:%7E:text=During%20overload%20resolution%2C%20non%2Dstatic,has%20the%20lvalue%20ref%2Dqualifier.) , which says that

> During overload resolution, ***non-static cv-qualified member function*** of class X is treated as a function that takes an implicit parameter of type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X if it has no ref-qualifiers or if it has the lvalue ref-qualifier. Otherwise (if it has rvalue ref-qualifier), it is treated as a function taking an implicit parameter of type rvalue reference to cv-qualified X.

Questions:

1.What about the member functions ***without any ref-qualifier***? They would be treated as functions that implicitly declared with the `lvalue` ref-qualifier. Am I right?

2.Why it's limited to ***non-static cv-qualified*** member function(i.e.  see the text in bold) other than ***non-static*** member function? What are the differences between them?

Comment: The first question is answered by "_lvalue reference to cv-qualified X if it has no ref-qualifiers_", no? The second question is simply that _static_ member functions are not called on objects, so they ought to not have an implicit object parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> .What about the member functions without any ref-qualifier?

This has answer in the statement that you quoted. In particular(note the bold part in the quoted statement below),

> During overload resolution, non-static cv-qualified member function of class X is treated as a function that takes an *implicit parameter of type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X* **if it has no ref-qualifiers**...

This means that for non-static `const` qualified member functions which are without any ref-qualifiers, during overload resolution they are treated as if they have an implicit object parameter of type `const X&`.

---

> Why it's limited to non-static cv-qualified member function

It's limited to non-static member function because static member functions don't make use of `this` pointer. That is, they(static member functions) are not called on objects. In other words, they don't have a `this` pointer associated with them.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I still have difficulty in understanding your first answer. Could you please explain that in simple words?
To my current understanding, I think it means that the non-static member functions would be treated as functions that (implicitly) declared with the lvalue ref-qualifier.

Comment: @John Say we have a non-staitc member function named `func` that is `const` qualfiied. For example: `struct Name{ void func() const{ } };`. According to the quoted statement, this member function has an implicit parameter which is of type `const X&`. Similarly, lets say this time we have: `struct Name{ void func() const&{ } };`. Then according to the quoted statement again, this member function will also have an implicit parameter that will be of type `const X&`. Is this simple enough? Also, note the "during overload resolution" in the quoted statement.